# Android - MySQL connection error on wampserver

Tags: php, android, mysql, wampserver

I am trying to connect my android app with database on my local server. It is actually connecting but when its trying to perform insertion into database , I am getting errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_login in C:\wamp\www\webapp\register.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: user_password in C:\wamp\www\webapp\register.php on line 5
Notice: Undefined index: user_phonenumber in C:\wamp\www\webapp\register.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: user_email in C:\wamp\www\webapp\register.php on line 7
```

On my register.php i have

```
require "init.php";

$user_login = $_POST["user_login"];
$user_password = $_POST["user_password"];
$user_phonenumber = $_POST["user_phonenumber"];
$user_email = $_POST["user_email"];

$sql_query = "insert into user_db values('$user_login','$user_password','$user_phonenumber','$user_email');";
```

Android code :

```
URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                Log.d("in background", " connected");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_login","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(Loginstr,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_password","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(Passwordstr,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_phonenumber","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(Numberstr,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_email","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode( Emailstr,"UTF-8");
                        bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
```

I would also ask how to make one thing. In my database I have created to be filled by new user and one field created to hold unique id for user. My question is: After creation of new user , will this id field be filed with new uniqe id corelated with user? (`AUTO_INCREMENT` option is marked). If not , what should i do to make such a thing.

I am really new with SQL and PHP so i hope I have explained everything correct. Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) explains the error. I would guess the POST part of your HTTP request is being set improperly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are not getting 'errors', but you are getting 'notices'.

You can disable displaying of notices with the following line:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

For development use it is good to set the error reporting to display the errors 'on the page':

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

But for production this should be set to false, and errors logged somewhere else.

Secondly, if your MySQL table has a primary key with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` then your insert will automatically generate an Id.  You can access this with the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` MySQL function (or the PHP equivalent, depending on wether you are using mysqli or PDO).